# Execute a cron-tab till a certain time

Tags: cron

I have a script that I would like to run every five minutes. Therefore I have something like this:

```
*/5 * * * * /dostuff.sh
```

Works fine. However, the script should run till a certain time. Could anybody explain to me how I can run a script every five minutes WHILE is not later then a certain time

Comment: define "later than a certain time"

Comment: I mean the script should run till it's 6pm

Comment: every 5 minutes from 00.00 until 17.55 or 18.00? Please [edit] giving all these details.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you need to run it each 5 minutes everyday from 10h to 16h:

```
*/5 10-16 * * * /dostuff.sh
```